# Laravel eloquent SQL query with OR and AND with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know that sql AND can be achieved by consecutive where clauses. and OR with where(condition,'OR'). 
I want to choose all the messages from message table where sentTo = editor_id AND sentFrom= currentUser_id OR where sentTo = currentUser_id AND sentFrom = editor_id.
I have this query which I am trying to get the result through,

```
    $this->data['messages'] = Message::where(function ($query) use($uId) {
        $query->where('sentTo', '=', $this->data['currentUser']->id)
            ->orWhere('sentFrom', '=', $uId);
            })
    ->where(function ($query) use($uId){
             $query->where('sentTo', '=', $uId)
                     ->orWhere('sentFrom', '=', $this->data['currentUser']->id);
            })
    ->get();
```

How can I do this? Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit confuse as you didn't provide parentheses to know which operator precedence you want.

Assuming you want `WHERE (editor_id=$editorId AND sentFrom=$currentUserId) OR (sentTo=$currentUserId AND sentFrom=$editorId)` then latest version of Laravel allows you to do:

```
    Message::where(['editor_id' => $editorId, 'sentFrom' => $currentUserId])
    ->orWhere(['sentTo' => $currentUserId, 'sentFrom' => $editorId])->get();
```

No need to use closures.

Comment: Wow! I did not know it can be done this way. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: This is great. I used something like this myself with Laravel 4.2

Comment: over a year later and this is still the best answer on the internet. Works in 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->data['messages'] = Message::where(function ($query) use($uId) {
    $query->where('sentTo', '=', $this->data['currentUser']->id)
          ->where('sentFrom', '=', $uId);
})-> orWhere(function ($query) use($uId){
    $query->where('sentTo', '=', $uId)
          ->Where('sentFrom', '=', $this->data['currentUser']->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but I am getting currentUser object from _construct() function in the controller. So It is available everywhere. However, your solution won't work as you are passing an object as an id. Also, if the currentUser->id was not in scope I would have got an undefined error, which I am not getting. All I get  in the result is Null. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is caused by $this make sure that you have the $this->data['currentUser']->id before doing the request.

Comment: I got it worked,`$this->data['messages'] = Message::where(function ($query) use($uId) {
            $query->where('sentTo', '=', $this->data['currentUser']->id)
                ->Where('sentFrom', '=', $uId);
                })
        ->orwhere(function ($query) use($uId){
                 $query->where('sentTo', '=', $uId)
                         ->Where('sentFrom', '=', $this->data['currentUser']->id);
                })
        ->get();` Thanks for your efforts @Issam