# Laravel 4.2 - Eloquent WHERE clause with OR and reverse parameters

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have Eloquent statement in Laravel 4.2 that looks like this

```
    $user_message_block = Message::where('responder_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();
```

Then if `$user_message_block` doesn't exist I also have to check for a reverse case scenario and I do it like this...

```
    if(!$user_message_block){
        $user_message_block = Message::where('responder_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                            ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();
    }
```

What I really would like to do is run a single query that checks for both scenarios at once..

In pseudo expression I need something like this:

```
$user_message_block = Message::where('responder_id', '=', Auth::user()->id, 
                                 'AND', 'user_id', '=', $user->id, 
                                 'OR', 'responder_id', '=', $user->id, 
                                 'AND', 'user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

So basically I need to

```
SELECT Message where (responder_id=x AND user_id=y) OR where (responder_id=y AND user_id=x)
```

How could I do this using Eloquent. I am unable to find more about OR and AND statements used with Eloquent.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

After more looking I found that this seems to work (still testing a lot)

```
$user_message_block = 
        Message::where(['responder_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'user_id' => $user->id])
             ->orWhere(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'responder_id' => $user->id])
             ->first();
```

OR

```
$user_message_block = 
        Message::where(['responder_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'user_id' => $user->id])
             ->orWhere(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'responder_id' => $user->id])
             ->get();
```

Are there any drawbacks to this that I need to consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be very complicated to do in Eloquent but this does exactly what you need using Laravel's query builder without reverting to raw SQL.

```
    DB::table('messages')
        ->where(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('responder_id', '=', 'x')
            ->where('user_id', '=', 'y');
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('responder_id', '=', 'y')
                  ->where('user_id', '=', 'x');
        })
        ->get();
```

This is what I get from running a `toSql()` on it:

```
select * from `messages` where (`responder_id` = ? and `user_id` = ?) or (`responder_id` = ? and `user_id` = ?)
```

Try this to see if it works with Eloquent.

```
Message::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('responder_id', '=', 'x')
          ->where('user_id', '=', 'y');
})->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('responder_id', '=', 'y')
          ->where('user_id', '=', 'x');
})->get();
```

It should work.

Comment: mmmm,, I just found something about Eloquent that seems to work,, I'll update my question. It looks like I can pass arrays of information and use ->orWhere eloquent clause.

Comment: If that has provided a solution to you please accept it as an answer.

Comment: I am using a solution I posted above. I'll test this later to see if there are any apparent differences that make this solution more viable.

Comment: It only gets the first record.

Comment: I need only the first record. The solution you posted throws errors,,

Comment: My actual expression looks like this: 


    $user_message_block = Message::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('responder_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
          ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
})->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('responder_id', '=', $user->id)
          ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();

and I am getting user not defined

Comment: Yes and what does this return.

Comment: I updated the comment,, sorry,, I am getting user not defined,,, where as in my version of the query it is defined..

Comment: User not defined?  This has nothing to do with the query itself

Comment: Read here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or this is the proper way to do advanced wheres.

Comment: I have seen that post. OK.. so after testing a bit, yes your query works.. but for some reason (could be laravel/eloquent version) User model can't be accessed from within the closure in this expression. I will have to look deeper into that. Oddly,, in my version of the query User is accessible. Maybe this is a call for another question ..

Comment: Where did you find that query?  Never seen anything like that passing an array in a where clause.

Comment: Alex from phpacademy (you can youtube it) did something similar to that in one of his laravel lessons.. AND I will try to find stack post that uses it as a solution..

Comment: Interesting.  I guess both work then.  Glad you were able to solve the problem regardless.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539439/laravel-eloquent-sql-query-with-or-and-and-with-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

I credited Noah for the solution on account of providing a working solution and the effort he made in helping me out. I did end up using a different solution however..

```
$user_message_block = 
    Message::where(['responder_id' => 'x', 'user_id'      => 'y'])
           ->orWhere(['user_id'    => 'x', 'responder_id' => 'y'])
           ->get();
```

In my speciffic case I only need the first record found so this works for me

```
$user_message_block = 
    Message::where(['responder_id' => 'x', 'user_id'      => 'y'])
           ->orWhere(['user_id'    => 'x', 'responder_id' => 'y'])
           ->first();
```

Suffice it to say,, I found a solution similar to mine in phpacademy videos by Alex. And I stumbled upon this too [Laravel eloquent SQL query with OR and AND with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539439/laravel-eloquent-sql-query-with-or-and-and-with-where-clause)